# ADSL Connections

Tags: adsl, broadband, redundancy, failover

Can you have two ADSL connections on a single phone line? Or by law of IT, do two Broadband connections require two separate phone lines and BT master sockets?

Comment: maybe for a backup you could use a company that gives wireless broadband like BTFON or BTopenworld on PAYG in the UK. It'd be quicker than dialup as a backup.

Comment: You need two physical lines. Sending two signals over the same line would cause major interference and neither would work. The second would probably not even be able to train and any attempt to train would probably kill the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two phone lines as there must be a separate ADSL device at the DSLAM.

Even with that you would need a device to load blanace the two links or something similar depending on your use of the two connections.

Comment: What do companies do for redundancy then?  have 2 phone lines?

Comment: Most places I worked at had dedicated lines for main access (fibre), and DSL as emergency backup.

Comment: Redundancy is always on multiple circuits, whether they are the same type or not (ie two DSL, one DSL and one Fiber, one DSL and one Cable, etc). The other common options are things like bonded DSL or bonded T1s, but they still require multiple circuits.